# Android: how to move standard elements (like EditText) by touch event?

Tags: android, view, move

I can override onTouchEvent, but there is no x and y coordinates to set in the EditText or usual View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to adjust the rules of whatever container (e.g., `RelativeLayout`) holds the widget to be whatever it is you want it to be as a result of the `onTouchEvent()`. Usually, this is accomplished by adjusting the container-specific `LayoutParams` associated with the widget being moved.